# Get all network requests from firefox automatically to python

Tags: python, firefox

I want to browse firefox manually and send all the network logs of the pages I vist to python so that I could filter the logs on the fly and store them in a .txt file. I would need to keep monitoring the .txt file to edit anything manually if needed.

[image]

What would be the best way of going about this?

I was looking into selenium and connecting to an already open session, but thouight if there was some other better way.